# Is it possible to detect a CSS rule change for a class with Chrome dev tools?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-devtools

I have included a stylesheet on the page, and then tweak it with "styles" panel in Chrome. Is it possible (with an extension) to get notified about such in-place edits of styles in that stylesheet when working with dev-tools? I know how to do it for styles of individual elements, but I'm not editing the style, but the class rule in the stylesheet itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

Add a CSS class to an element
Use the Styles pane to see how an element looks when a CSS class is applied to or removed from an element.

Right-click the Add a class to me! element below and select Inspect.

Add a class to me!
Click .cls. DevTools reveals a text box where you can add classes to the selected element.

Type color_me in the Add new class text box and then press Enter. A checkbox appears below the Add new class text box, where you can toggle the class on and off. If the Add a class to me! element had any other classes applied to it, you'd also be able to toggle them from here.

Refer this:
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/

Comment: no i need to be able to get notified programmatically when the style changes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).